# The input is a three-digit number. Print the arithmetic mean of its digits

Tags: c++

I have a homework assignment. The input is a three-digit number. Print the arithmetic mean of its digits. I am new to C++ and cannot write the code so that it takes 1 number as input to a string. I succeed, only in a column.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    std::cout << (a+b+c)/3. << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you write it in Python it looks like this. But I don't know how to write the same thing in C ++ :(

```
number = int(input())
digital3 = number % 10
digital2 = (number//10)%10
digital1 = number//100
summ = (digital1+digital2+digital3)/3
print(summ)
```

Comment: According to the problem statement, all variables must be entered on one line. And I can only enter them separately.

Comment: Hint: Don't read 3 numbers, but 1 string. Reading a string will make it easier to get the individual digits.

Comment: @jarmod he probably want to be able to input 123 and not 1 2 3

Comment: did you try to read the input as a string? There is no string in the code you posted

Comment: It's pretty easy to convert your Python logic to C++: https://onlinegdb.com/qPEUD3kMM You may still want to use strings though to validate input.

Comment: Do the same with `/` instead of `//`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 And how to translate from one language to another on this site, I just found how to change them in the development environment

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Are you asking something?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 sorry for my bad english. You said that on this site you can convert from one programming language to another, but how to do it?

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying that. I'm just saying that you can write a C++ program very similar to the python one you have that implements a similar logic. Check the link, I've made an example of this.

Comment: Do you want to compute the average as a whole number (as I think you did in the python snippet) or as the actual rational value?

Comment: @Bob_ yeah  whole number

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 okay anyway thank you,  and forgive me for my English, I also just learn it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct translation from Python differs mostly in punctuation and the addition of types:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    int digital3 = number % 10;
    int digital2 = (number/10)%10;
    int digital1 = number/100;
    int summ = (digital1+digital2+digital3)/3;
    std::cout << summ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: what if 4 digits number was entered?

Comment: @SHR Then it would not be the problem OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you use three different numbers and take the mean of their sum (not the sum of three-digits number). The right way is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << ((a/100) + ((a/10)%10) + (a%10))/3.<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(a%100)%10 == a%10`

Comment: what if 4 digits number was entered?

Comment: @SHR you can manually add boundaries checking. that is not item of question

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This answer is incorrect. I thought the goal was to average three numbers. Not three DIGITS. Bad reading on my part**

*Old answer *

> I'm not sure I'm interpreting the question correctly. I ran your code
> and confirmed it does what I expected it to...

> Are you receiving three digit chars (0-9) and finding the average of
> them? If so, I'd trying using a
>
> - for loop using getChar()
>
> Here is a range of functions that may be of use to you.
>
> - Regex strip
> - Convert string to int: int myInt = stoi(myStr.c_str())
> - Convert int to string: std::string myStr = myInt.to_string()
>
> If you need to improve your printing format
>
> - [Using printf](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/)
> - If using cout, you can kindve hack your way through it!

Comment: " The input is a three-digit number.". Ops code will not sucessfully calculate the mean of digits of a 3digit number

Comment: You are right. I misinterpreted the question. I thought its was: three numbers being entered then avg'd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `std::string`:

**EDIT** added digits check

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>    
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    if(s.length() == 3 && isdigit(s[0]) && isdigit(s[1]) && isdigit(s[2]))
    {
        std::cout<<double(s[0] + s[1] + s[2])/3 - '0'<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout<<"Wrong input"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The input is a three-digit number.

If it means, you'll be given a number that will always have `3` digits, then you can try the following approach.

> - Separate each digit
> - Find all digits sum
> - Divide the sum by 3

If you're given the number as a string, all you've to do is convert that `string` into `int`. Rest of the approach is the same as abve.

Sample code:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    int sum = (a % 10);  // adding 3rd digit
    a /= 10;
    sum += (a % 10);  // adding 2nd digit
    a /= 10;
    sum += (a % 10);  // adding 1st digit
    
    std::cout << (double)sum / 3.0 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```